# How to retain the selected value in the dropdown list

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, html-select

I have a `DropDownList` in a header of a `GridView` and I bind its data in the `RowDataBound` and place it in the `UpdatePanel` . I want to retain the selected value after selection(postback) . how ?

here I fill in the dropdownlist

Protected Sub gvStaffList_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvStaffList.RowDataBound

```
If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Header Then

    ' Fill the header dropdownlist from the datatable and displaying only the unique values (NOT from database directly) 

    ' ============================= Supervisor name ======================================================
    Dim ddlSupervisors As DropDownList = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("ddlSupervisors"), DropDownList)
    For x As Integer = 0 To data.Rows.Count - 1
        If ddlSupervisors.Items.FindByValue(data.Rows(x).Item("SuperId")) Is Nothing Then
            ddlSupervisors.Items.Add(New ListItem(data.Rows(x).Item("SuperName"), data.Rows(x).Item("SuperId")))
        End If
    Next
    ddlSupervisors.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("All", "All"))

    ' ============================= Supervisor name ======================================================
    Dim ddlPostTitle As DropDownList = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("ddlPostTitle"), DropDownList)
    For x As Integer = 0 To data.Rows.Count - 1

        If ddlPostTitle.Items.FindByValue(data.Rows(x).Item(1)) Is Nothing Then
            ddlPostTitle.Items.Add(New ListItem(data.Rows(x).Item(1), data.Rows(x).Item(1)))
        End If
    Next
    ddlPostTitle.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("All", "All"))
```

Comment: DO you have a SelectedIndexChanged Event in the dropdownlist

Comment: hello,you can use session to store selected value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello use session like that:

```
Session["selecteditem"] = "your value";
```

on c#
;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can store it in session during the IndexChanged event and just pull it back.

Answer (score 0):

Try to refill your dropdownlist again after the postback and then you can retain the selected value of the dropdownlist after you fill it again.

Try it and let me know if there are any problems